# How to do a trustworthy ICO?

Tags: ico

From the looks of things, most ICOs are scams. It's an easy way to take in money and once it's in there isn't much incentive for the founders to continue working?

How is it possible to do an ICO where the founders only get paid when they achieve certain milestones?

Are there examples of trustworthy ICOs that limit the amount of fraud committed by the founders with mechanisms built into the smart contract/funding procedure?

Comment: I like to look for ICO rounds. Nobody needs $50 million in their first & only fund raising round for just a whitepaper. Create rounds and explain what each round is for, and how the funds are to be spend. Also, it's nice to have at least a demo available so I know the team _can_ do what they say they can do. Public team profiles are also nice so I can check the teams credentials and they are who they say they are.

Comment: I feel like they've flipped the idea of IPO's on it's head. Instead of investing into a company with a track record of success, you're gambling on many projects in the hope of success. It makes sense in some places, counterintuitive in most imo.

Comment: @Malone well your not even investing in the company. Just the currency of it

Comment: true, hoping that currency/token becomes a lucrative investment.  @EliezerSteinbock